# Rails validation message is treating percentage signs and double periods oddly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2

Using Rails 2.3.4, Ruby 1.8.7.

I have an ActiveRecord validation where I want to include the user's input in the error message. The simplified version of I'm doing something like this:

```
record.errors.add attr, "'#{calculated_value}' is not valid.'
```

Where `calculated_value` is a portion of the user's input of a larger value.

I've found that if the user enters values that contain certain characters, odd things can happen. If `calculated_value` contains `%s`, `%s` gets replaced by the full value the user entered. If `calculated_value` contains `..`, I got:

```
ArgumentError - interning empty string from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/vendor/i18n-0.1.3/lib/i18n.rb:196:in `to_sym'.
```

I would like to know how I can disable the functionality or how I can escape these values. I tried escaping `%s` to `%%s`, sprintf-style, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I dunno whether this method was available in rals 2.3.4.  But can you try out activerecord [Inclusion](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#inclusion). This helper validates that the attributes’ values are included in a given set.   So your code will be something like

```
class YourModel< ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :calculated_value, :inclusion => { :in => %w(Valid Values you want),
    :message => "%{calculated_value} is not a valid value" }
end
```

Comment: My validation is more complicated than a list of acceptable values. It's not that I have a problem with the logic to determine an incorrect value, it's that the string I give to record.errors.add gets rewritten if it contains certain sequences of characters, like %s.

Comment: @np_ can u site example of the scenario what exactly is happening